# Property does not exist on type when using Or for multiple types

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular component I have an `Input` that will be provided 1 of 2 types.

```
@Input() profile: UserProfileDetails | BusinessProfileDetails;
```

The profile template is simple and I'd like to use only the single template so I am not duplicating code. But because the types differ in properties I am receiving a template error.

```
export interface UserProfileDetails {
  createdOn: Date;
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

```
export interface BusinessProfileDetails {
  businessId: string;
  businessLocation: string;
  createdOn: Date;
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

and the code in my template:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{profile.name}}</h1>
  <div>{{profile.createdOn}}</div>
  <div>{{profile.id}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="profile?.businessId">{{profile.businessId}}</div>
  <div *ngIf="profile?.businessLocation">{{profile.businessLocation}}</div>
</div>
```

I believe I understand why I am receiving the error, but I'm unsure how to resolve the issue while still using the `or` condition `@Input() profile: UserProfileDetails | BusinessProfileDetails;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that angular's [Template type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) seems enabled.

With the related settings enabled, the types of the objects used within the view are validated. If by any chance the object would not have one of the properties, these validations would cause the error you are facing.

Specifically in your case because the interface `UserProfileDetails` does not have some of the properties used in the view, angular is considering the use of `businessId` or `businessLocation` an error.

there are some options to fix it:

- disable Template type checking  (I would not recommend that)
- use a generic type for the `profile` variable (I would also not prefer this one)
- use a pipe to cast the type of the object within the view. (my preference)

```
<div *ngIf="(profile | castProfileType)?.businessId">{{profile.businessId}}</div>
<div *ngIf="(profile | castProfileType)?.businessLocation">{{profile.businessLocation}}</div>
```

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'castProfileType',
})
export class CastProfileTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: profileObject) {
    return Object.keys(value).includes('businessId') ? <BusinessProfileDetails>value : <UserProfileDetails>value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only reference properties that are common to both interfaces with `|`. Unintuitively `|` is called a `union` type in TypeScript.

Try an intersection type with `&` instead

Comment: Helpful answer! I feel like intersection isn't right either, though, as you don't want to combine the types, you just want to be warned that a value might be undefined and you need to safely check for properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with:

```
<div *ngIf="profile.hasOwnProperty('businessId')">{{profile.businessId}}</div>
<div *ngIf="profile.hasOwnProperty('businessLocation')">{{profile.businessLocation}}</div>
```

Comment: You're checking if your object has a given property (you can also use a more modern `.hasOwn()` instead of `hasOwnPoperty()`) - and only one of your two possible types has it, so I don't see how can it affect the safety.

Comment: @Drenai true, but it goes for all other keys: name, createdOn etc. it's not an issue with these two.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a workaround using a function that check attribut on `profile` using `in` operator. Not the best solution but you'll be able to keep the interfaces union as you wished :

**Component**

```js
getValue(
  attribut: string,
  obj: UserProfileDetails | BusinessProfileDetails
): any {
  if (attribut in obj) {
    return obj[attribut];
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<div>
  <h1>{{ profile.name }}</h1>
  <div>{{ profile.createdOn }}</div>
  <div>{{ profile.id }}</div>
  <div>{{ getValue('businessId', profile) }}</div> <!-- can be improved using a check method combined with ngIf -->
  <div>{{ getValue('businessLocation', profile) }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

go to `tsconfig` file and change strict mode (line 8 if I remember correctly) to `false`